# Angular File Upload Plugin: file selection not working properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I want to let the user only upload *.txt file with the Angular JS File Upload Plugin (https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload). I have the following problem:

In Firefox, when you click the "Select file" button, any file is selectable. In Chrome and IE, however, you can only select *.txt files which is the way it should work. Why does it not work in Firefox? Does anybody know a workaround?

Here comes my code:

```
<div ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="button" ng-file-select ng-file-change="upload($files)" ng-multiple="multiple" ng-accept="'.txt'">Select File</div>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/nmdcwf3w/172/

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug in FireFox you can find it here it is reported and fixed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=826176

Comment: I had the similar problem and it is not possible to fix it, its still a problem with FF. You can try adding ng-accept="'text/plain'" only for FF and it will add option for txt files in filter but it will not be selected as a default one (it will show All files (.) as a default one with possibility to change to Text documents)